# Adding a Query to Azure log analytics using ARM

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am new to azure trying to figure out how to add a query to log analytics using ARM. I have surfed through the Azure Documentation but didn't find the exact data for the mentioned task.
What could be the approach?

Comment: do you mean running the log analytics query using azure cli or through PowerShell cmdlets ? or can you give some brief explanation what you are trying to do and also with the documentation if you are following

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft Documentation gives clear example how to add query to Azure LogAnalytics using Azure Resource Manager and
Taken reference from **[Resource Manager template samples for log queries in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/resource-manager-log-queries?tabs=bicep)** and

***Parameter.json***:

```
{

"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",

"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

"parameters": {

"workspaceName": {

"value": "rithwik"

},

"location": {

"value": "West Central US"

}

}

}
```